# Unable to install windows 7 over ubuntu 14.04. ( to remove ubuntu )

Tags: windows-7

I want to install win 7 over ubuntu but the windows installation has stopped when appear the "Starting Windows" screen (for the first time). I convert my hard disk to mbr, from gpt and I deleted all partition, but the same problem. The screen is just froze.  Now I don't have an operating sistem on my hp envy laptop, just an ubuntu live usb. 
What can I do ?